# Get sound's total time and current time?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a player in flash ActionScript 3. I need to take a the total time of the sound file and current time of the sound file.
My code:

```
function onPlayProgress(evt:Event):void {
            var sndLength:int = Math.ceil(snd.length /(snd.bytesLoaded / snd.bytesTotal));
            var seekbar = 100 * (channel.position / sndLength);
            playBar.seekbar.x = seekbar*5.8;
            var _totalTime:Number = (((snd.length /(snd.bytesLoaded / snd.bytesTotal))*0.001/60));
```

What is current time?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on what the code sample you provided is trying to communicate, but if you want to get the current position of a sound that's playing you would do something like this:

```
protected var sound:Sound; 
protected var soundChannel:SoundChannel;

protected function loadSound():void
{
    sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("path_to_sound.mp3"));
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);
{

protected function onSoundLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);
    soundChannel = sound.play();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}

//Calculuate the sound time
protected function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var minutes:uint = Math.floor(soundChannel.position / 1000 / 60);
    var seconds:uint = Math.floor(soundChannel.position / 1000) % 60;
    trace('position: ' + minutes + ':' + seconds);        
};
```

Comment: sound.length returns the length of the sound in milliseconds. Convert that value in the same way the current position is being converted. It's a little confusing b/c on one hand you have to use the Sound object and on the other you have to use the SoundChannel object. Check Adobe's documentation... it's quite complete.

Comment: hmm the conversion and the channel position are very diffrent :). i think i need to check the API doc for this... :( . . .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
sound.length cannot be taken as the total time, it is the total time of the loaded stream. If you debug the code, you'll find the sound.length is changing untill the audio is totally loadded.
But I have no idea to get the total time yet...
I calculate it like this, 
estimatedTotalTimeLength = sound.bytesTotal/sound.bytesLoaded * sound.length;