# Progress bar in a Flash MP3 Player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have coded a simple XML driven MP3 player. I have used Sound and SoundChannel objects and method but I can´t find a way of make a progress bar.

I don´t need a loading progress I need a song progress status bar.

Canbd anybody help me?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Theres is the code.

```
var musicReq: URLRequest;
var thumbReq: URLRequest;
var music:Sound = new Sound();
var sndC:SoundChannel;
var currentSnd:Sound = music;
var position:Number;
var currentIndex:Number = 0;
var songPaused:Boolean;
var songStopped:Boolean;
var lineClr:uint;
var changeClr:Boolean;
var xml:XML;
var songList:XMLList;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Loaded);

loader.load(new URLRequest("musiclist.xml"));

var thumbHd:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
thumbHd.x = 50;
thumbHd.y = 70;
addChild(thumbHd);

function Loaded(e:Event):void{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    songList = xml.song;
    musicReq = new URLRequest(songList[0].url);
    thumbReq = new URLRequest(songList[0].thumb);
    music.load(musicReq);
    sndC = music.play();
    title_txt.text = songList[0].title + " - " + songList[0].artist;

    loadThumb();
    sndC.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextSong);
}

function loadThumb():void{
    var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    thumbReq = new URLRequest(songList[currentIndex].thumb);
    thumbLoader.load(thumbReq);
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var thumb:Bitmap = (Bitmap)(e.target.content);
    var holder:MovieClip = thumbHd;
    holder.addChild(thumb);
}

prevBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSong);
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSong);
playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSong);

function prevSong(e:Event):void{
    if(currentIndex > 0){
        currentIndex--;
    }
    else{
        currentIndex = songList.length() - 1;
    }

    var prevReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(songList[currentIndex].url);
    var prevPlay:Sound = new Sound(prevReq);
    sndC.stop();
    title_txt.text = songList[currentIndex].title + " - " + songList[currentIndex].artist;
    sndC = prevPlay.play();
    currentSnd = prevPlay;
    songPaused = false;
    loadThumb();
    sndC.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextSong);
}

function nextSong(e:Event):void {
    if(currentIndex
```

And here the code for the lenght and position. It´s inside a MovieClip. That´s why I use absolute path for find the Sound object.

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSpeaker);

var initWidth:Number = this.SpkCone.width;
var initHeight:Number = this.SpkCone.height;
var rootObj:Object = root;

function moveSpeaker(eventArgs:Event)
{
    var average:Number = ((rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.sndC.leftPeak + rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.sndC.rightPeak) / 2) * 10;
//  trace(average); 
//  trace(initWidth + ":" + initHeight);
    trace(rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.sndC.position + "/" + rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.music.length);
    this.SpkCone.width = initWidth + average;
    this.SpkCone.height = initHeight + average; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a normalized floating point value ( the percent complete ) by using: SoundChannel.position / Sound.length. Then you can use that value as a scalar for your sound playback progress indicator.

Psuedo Code:

```
// -- set the x scale of the progress bar to the percent complete
progbar.scaleX = channel.position / sound.length;
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I have tried this but the the lenght value is always bigger than the position value even when the song has been finished. For example: Position at 100%: 5944.308390022676 Lenght: 7392.65306122449 Do you know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you monitoring the playback... via enter-frame or some other event?

Comment: You are tracing out the sound object "music":


trace(rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.sndC.position + "/" + rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.music.length);

While in your function prevSound() you are never setting the new sound to the "music" var. You are setting it to a var called "currentSnd".
Maybe you might want to try this in the enter frame handler:
trace(rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.sndC.position + "/" + rootObj.audioPlayer_mc.currentSnd.length);

Comment: Nothing friend. Here is the dif: 5851.428571428572/7365.65306122449 when the song finish :(

Comment: Ok, try setting the "music" var to the "prevPlay" var inside the "prevSong" function. 

Like this: music = prevPlay; 
If that doesn't work, try testing w/ another mp3.

Comment: Nothing :( I will try with another song. Do you have some code where this stuff works fine?

Comment: Nothing with another song. Damn it!

Comment: I answered a similar question and provided some code that might help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758752/action-script-3-get-sounds-total-time-and-current-time/1761068#1761068

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Sound class has a "length" property indicating the length of the sound and the SoundChannel has a "position" property indicating the position of the sound currently playing. Use these 2 properties as data for a ProgressBar component.

Comment: Thanks Christophe. I have tried this but the the lenght value is always bigger than the position value even when the song has been finished.  

For example: 

Position at 100%: 5944.308390022676 
Lenght: 7392.65306122449

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure these properties are for the same sound? How are you playing your mp3 file?

Comment: Yes, the same. But I´m using an XML with a list of song. Perhaps there is the reason. Any suggestion? Any alternative?

Comment: I don't see how this might be related to the fact that you are loading a list from XML. Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen for the complete event, and inside of that set the scaleX to 1.